# Evaluating WEXITSTATUS in C using RHEL5

Tags: c, posix

I wrote a deamon recently that I use for automating movement of data between our various servers, along with other things. I'm using rsync, and rsync is working swimmingly.

However, I had to add a specific exclude in my rsync invocation on one of our servers, and since then, my code no longer ever sees success when using rsync.  I have tried running the rsync manually, and it returns success every time.  Furthermore, even when the daemon invokes rsync, it DOES copy all files successfully, so the problem is not with rsync.  Yet, the doSomeOtherThing() function is not called, and instead I get the error email that errorEmail3() throws at me.  This is in GNU C.

Here's my code:

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  char *args[NUM_ARGS]
  args[0] = strdup("rsync");
  ...
  ...
  execvp(args[0], args);
  fprintf(stderr, "execvp ain't workin\n");
  exit(1);
}
else if (pid == -1) {
  erroremail1();
  return;
}
else {
  int childstat;
  if (waitpid(pid, &childstat, 0) == -1) {
    perror("waitpid");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    if (!WIFEXITED(childstat)) {
      errorEmail2();
    }
    else {
      if (WEXITSTATUS(childstat) == EXIT_SUCCESS) {
        doSomeOtherThing();
      }
      else {
        errorEmail3();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have sys/wait.h included, along with all the other relevant header files.

I'm probably missing something very dumb and obvious here, and I'd appreciate a second pair of eyes to look at this.

EDIT: copied code incorrectly, fixed
EDIT 2: Fixed another typo.
EDIT 3: added exact code for error checking

Comment: What is `EXIT_STATUS`? Shouldn't this be `EXIT_SUCCESS`?

Comment: OT: The call to `waitpid()` misses error checking. If is fails `childstat` is read out uninitialised, which in turn provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Another bad copy. Sorry, About to fix.

Comment: From your "bad copies" I get the impression you aren't showing "the real" code.

Comment: @alk I have ruled out that the problem is with waitpid() failing, but good catch

Comment: Ever and always perform error checking on (system) calls returning values being used afterwards!

Comment: @alk I am not allowed to put up "the real code", per my company's policy.

Comment: So your real code performs error checking on `waitpid()`? If not apply it, retest and come back here.

Comment: I did put in a check, and still no dice.

Comment: You might like to add the check to your question, not changing what is already there. Also it would be intersting to know what value for status is returned, which exit code is given by WEXITSTATUS and what program actually returned it.

Comment: Where is the code that prints all the interesting values, like the PID of the `rsync` and the exit status, and the actual value returned by `waitpid()`, and the raw value in `childstat` and so on?  If you don't have that data available, you don't know what is going wrong.  Make sure you print all such relevant information, at least when you run the daemon with a debug flag (consider making it `-d N` for various values of N, so you can generate more or less data as needed).  The "execvp isn't working" message doesn't give you any help, either; it should print the values in `argv`.

Comment: Also, the `else { if (...) { ... } else { if (...) { ... } } }` style indentation is bad C style.  Use `else if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... }` saving levels of nesting.